# Где прочитать граммотные ресурсы на Android Developer про использование разных фич?

Tags: android

Где прочитать про ток, как правильно использовать API, а то, прошу прощения, уже надоело каждый раз спрашивать на hashcode и тому подобных ресурсах, когда сам могу прочитать и понять, но не знаю в каком разделе, ибо в Reference написано лишь только описание методов и т.п., а как пользоваться и в какой последовательности, хз, в API Guides написано не всё. Я веду к тому,что мне нужно предоставление инфы  на подобие описания жизни Activity, когда onCreate вызывается, когда onPause и т.д. только для Adapter и т.п. Чтобы не искать по просторам интернета, а прочитать инструкцию, понять и использовать. Заранее благодарю!

И ещё маленький под вопрос. Я использую Eclipse, меня очень волнует, пойдёт ли моё приложение на API lvl 11 и выше? Т.е. как узнать,какие методы не подходят для данной версии, чтобы не сидеть и не просматривать каждую использованную библиотеку?

Comment: Приобретите бумажный вариант мануала по Android. Реальный толк будет только от бумажного. Ну а подхватывать информацию можно и из сети. Это идеальная комбинация.
Вот, конкретно то, например, что касается жизненного цикла Activity( onCreate, onPause и т.д ) - это очень хорошо( с картинками ) описано в любом бумажном издании.

---
**И не используйте Eclipse для разработки под Android.**

Comment: Можно вполне использовать Eclipse для разработки. Уже больше года использую исключительно Eclipse. Обновляю периодически версию и всё. Не хочется холивара, но Gradle не нужен для простеньких приложений.

Comment: @Lucky_spirit IDEA пробовали? если да то почему до сих пор на эклипсе?

Comment: Пробовал. Не нашёл в ней ничего хорошего. Может потому что я ещё и на других языках писал и у меня нет чёткой привязки к IDE. Я считаю, что писать можно и в Блокноте, и в консоли. Главное - потом собрать проект.

Comment: @Lucky_spirit, в ваших изречениях нет рационального зерна: то, что Android Studio - лучшая IDE для разработки под Android - в целом, общепризнанный факт. То, что вы не сумели найти в ней "ничего хорошего", говорит лишь о том, что уровень вашей разработки под OS Android все еще где-то ниже среднего.

Comment: Во-первых, правильно говорить "заикаться". Зарекаться - это обещать что-то не делать. А во-вторых, ссылочку, пожалуйста, приведите, где указывается "общепризнанный факт". Пока Android Studio не выйдет из беты и на главной странице Download SDK её не появится, до тех пор это даже не конечный продукт.

Comment: Холивары на счет IDE - это бессмысленная затея. Но действительно , почему бы не использовать качественную среду. AS построена на IDEA, и на мой взгляд - это лучшее, что есть для  разработки под Android. Ну, не считая самой IDEA, которая, кстати, как вы говорите уже как раз "конечный продукт".

Answer (score 1):

["Разработка под Android с котятками"](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/index.php) и ["153 урока разработки под Android"](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom.html)

> > И ещё маленький под вопрос. Я использую Eclipse, меня очень волнует, пойдёт ли моё приложение на API lvl 11 и выше? Т.е. как узнать,какие методы не подходят для данной версии, чтобы не сидеть и не просматривать каждую использованную библиотеку?

Я бы посоветовал использовать AndroidStudio, она знает обо всех методах во всех подключенных API и подсветит там где надо, ну и в целом, она более подходит под разработку Android приложений, но это моё мнение, с ним могут некоторые не согласиться.

Comment: Про эти сайты я знаю,но там тоже далеко не всё,а сайт с котятками вообще за бабло только расширяет уроки. Я с AndroidStudio немного поработал,в целом понравилась, куда более приятна, но вы случаем не подскажите, как можно быстро и безболезненно перенести проект из Eclipse в AndroidStudio,а то у них файлы проекта немного по-другому расположены

Comment: @ua6xh, не знаю, кто бы не согласился, что Android Studio более приемлема, чем Eclipse..

Comment: @BORSHEVIK - только практиковать и юзать StackOwerflow. Сам страдаю от нехватки русскоязычной информации по тому, как ПРАВИЛЬНО писать, ибо постоянно сначала велосипед придумаю, а потом на стековерфлоу нахожу изящное решение через какой-нибудь стандартный паттерн. Ещё мне помогало разбирать исходники каких либо проектов с гитхаба или с того же developers.google - важно запоминать то, как пишут чуваки из гугла.

Comment: @BORSHEVIK - думаю только ручками. Я не знаю как в эклипсе, но андроид студия  по дефолту сейчас работает с gradle и вам не потребуется тащить с собой кучи библиотек. Я бы посоветовал создать новый проект в студии и аккуратно перенести туда файлы из проекта в эклипс, походу подключая всё необходимое в градл и манифесте.

Comment: Кстати,что это за Gradle такой,я так и не понял,зачем он, подгружает библиотеки?

Comment: @BORSHEVIK, на самом деле сборщик Gradle даже в чем-то лучше "устаревшего" Ant. Поэтому бежать от него не стоит - даже наоборот.

Comment: Я не соглашусь, что Android Studio лучше Eclipse. По крайней мере в текущем состоянии. В Eclipse почти всё, что нужно, можно настроить просто в Properties проекта. Например, тот же Build Target можно выбрать, просто поставив галочку напротив нужной версии. В Android Studio мне пришлось искать какой-то build.xml файл и вручную писать там версию. Как по мне, это вообще не удобно при переносе проекта с одного компьютера на другой. Плюс, если вы работаете с репозиториями и командой, то наступает большая проблема с редактированием этих xml файлов, так как у разных пользователей в разных папках SDK

Comment: Ну кому как, а для меня главное, что Eclipse бесплатен и позволяет писать еще и на чистом (без ADT) Java и не только.

Comment: @MDJHD, и IntelliJIdea( Community Edition ), и Android Studio также бесплатны. А что вы имели ввиду под "чистым Java" - не понятно. ADT - это плагин, упрощающий процесс разработки и отладки Android приложений.